# Bluetooth can't find any other device

Tags: 12.04, bluetooth

I'm using an Acer Aspire One 725 netbook with Ubuntu 12.04. When I try to set up a device my Laptops Bluetooth can't find any other device. The Bluetooth searching wizard is just searching for a new device but no results happen.

N.B.:  Bluetooth of my another device (e.g.:  mobiles) near to my laptop are in **VISIBLE** mode.

Comment: Did you try putting your device in pairing mode before starting *"Set Up New Device..."*?

Comment: yes I tried !!!

Comment: Posted on behalf of user [Nick](http://askubuntu.com/users/107528/nick): I seem to be having the same problem: [12.10 Bluetooth not detecting Wii remote](http://askubuntu.com/questions/244878/12-10-bluetooth-not-detecting-wii-remote) explains the issue I am seeing. Is `hcitool dev` returning a device for you?

Answer (score 0):

Try to do precisely the opposite :

- Put your Ubuntu PC in Bluetooth discoverable mode
- Pair it from the other device (your mobile phone) by following its normal procedure

Does that help ?

Comment: My mobile is also can't detect/find my laptop's bluetooth inspire of  my Ubuntu PC is visible...   :(